How do I define a substitution on Asciidoctor.convert
I want to specify a string value for the Ruby API of Asciidoctor, and want to have Asciidoctor substitute that value into the output.
I pieces the following together from the documentation, but it does not work.
Asciidoctor.convert adoc, attributes: { updated: src_mtime }
where adoc is a string like this:
:title: Some Title
:hardbreaks:

Introductory paragraph

== Section title

Paragraphs

[.text-right]
Last updated: {updated}

This will just generate "Last updated: {updated}" in the last paragraph, no substitution applied.
If I define updated as a header attribute, like so :updated: 1 Jan 2000, the substitution does take place, but it ignores the attributes from the Asciidoctor.convert call.
I've been banging my head on this all day, but to no avail.

Turns out the real issue was with the way the hash was constructed.
{ updated: src_mtime } creates a hash with a symbol as key.
{ 'updated' => src_mtime } creates a hash with a string as key.
Asciidoctor uses only string-keyed entries when looking for substitutions.

Asciidoctor needs to know the doctype for the conversion.
Here's a working example:
require 'asciidoctor'

src_mtime = File.mtime('index.adoc')
puts src_mtime

adoc = '
:title: Some Title
:hardbreaks:

Introductory paragraph

== Section title

Paragraphs

[.text-right]
Last updated: {updated}
'

puts Asciidoctor.convert adoc, doctype: :book, attributes: { 'updated' => src_mtime }

And the output:
$ ruby convert.rb 
2024-06-18 10:50:15 -0700
<div id="preamble">
<div class="sectionbody">
<div class="paragraph">
<p>Introductory paragraph</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sect1">
<h2 id="_section_title">Section title</h2>
<div class="sectionbody">
<div class="paragraph">
<p>Paragraphs</p>
</div>
<div class="paragraph text-right">
<p>Last updated: 2024-06-18 10:50:15 -0700</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>


Am I using the wrong kind of substitution? I had been assuming a format-agnostic substitution, i.e. one that happens before any rendering decisions are made. (This also explains why I could not make any progress: I was working off an invalid implicit assumption.)

I'm not sure I can answer those questions. You might ask in the Asciidoctor community in Zulip.
